# Not able to push the data for a list

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push this data to a list in javascript, but I am able to push name but not id as it contains a list and error which I get is **Shared.js:43 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

result = {"milestones": [{"id": [358682,302353]}
the javascript code which i used is

```
var res = result["milestones"], 
    Data = [];
for(var i = 0,len = res.length; i<len; i++) {
    Data.push({
        "id":res[i]["id"][0],
        "name":res[i]["name"]
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks like ```res``` is having a problem from the ```res = result["milestones"]``` statement. Could you check if res has the expected value or is it empty?

Comment: Your code is working fine here https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/gOagRge .. If possible reproduce you issue by creating an example like this..

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result = {"milestones": [{"id": [358682,302353], "name":"test"}]};
var res = result["milestones"],
    Data = [];
    for(var i = 0,len = res.length; i<len; i++){
        Data.push({
        "id":res[i]["id"][0],
        "name":res[i]["name"]
            })
    }
console.log (Data);
```

Your code is causing some problems, but I think that has to do with the transfer to stackoverflow. The example result has no name property. But the following code works fine:

```
var result = {"milestones": [{"id": [358682,302353], "name":"test"}]};
var res = result["milestones"],
    Data = [];
    for(var i = 0,len = res.length; i<len; i++){
        Data.push({
        "id":res[i]["id"][0],
        "name":res[i]["name"]
            })
    }
console.log (Data);
```